# Rename statement with wildcards

Tags: sas

I'm having a dataset with variables that have a time stamp in the name. Therefore importing the data I have an output like the following

```
NAME |Quantity Value at 31/12/2019|Value at 31/12/2019|Yield Exp 31/12/2019
FIDO |12                          |F                  |1
ALFA |20                          |2                  |4
BETA |3                           |5                  |2
ETA  |2                           |B65                |0
THETA|14                          |A40                |10
```

The final output do not needs these timestamp so I'd like to rename all variables removing the last part with the date. I'd expect the result to be something like that:

```
NAME |Quantity Value|Value|Yield Exp
FIDO |12            |F    |1
ALFA |20            |2    |4
BETA |3             |5    |2
ETA  |2             |B65  |0
THETA|14            |A40  |10
```

I'd like to use the rename function but i have to use wildcards because each time the input data is provided the time stamp is different. Is possible to use the rename function with widcards?
Moreover some variables have spaces and special carachters so I have to use the ''n notation while referring to them.

I've worked a code to get a dataset with all the variables name:

```
data base;
infile cards missover;
input 
NAME $ 'Quantity Value at 31/12/2019'n $ 'Value at 31/12/2019'n $ 'Yield Exp 31/12/2019'n $; datalines;
FIDO 12                          F                  1
ALFA 20                          2                  4
BETA 3                           5                  2
ETA  2                           B65                0
THETA 14                         A40                10
run;

proc sql ;
    create table BASE_COLUMN as
    select name 
    from sashelp.vcolumn
    where memname = "BASE"
  ;
quit ;

proc sql;
    update BASE_COLUMN
        set name = 
            case
                when name like "Quantity Value%" then "Quantity Value"
                when name like "Value at%" then "Value"
                when name like "Yield Exp%" then "Yield Exp"
            else name
end;
quit;
```

But i'm still struggling to use the BASE_COLUMN dataset to rename the original BASE dataset.

What's the best way to rename all the column name given a dataset with the right names?

Comment: [this](https://github.com/samkart/SASUtilityMacros/blob/master/renaming%20variables%20macro.sas) might help. This puts a prefix in the columns. You can change it to suit your needs.

Comment: I am not sure you could rename using wildcard in SAS. But the better approach would be to use SAS dictionary to rename the variables. You could see this paper for more understanding. https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi28/118-28.pdf

Comment: Did you really start with a dataset?  Or did you start with a text file that you read into a dataset?  If the later then why not just read the file using the variable names you want to start with?

Comment: Given that, after a few lines of proc update,  I have a dataset with the right column names (in the same order of the original dataset) how can i use that to rename all the variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is coming in as an existing dataset somewhere, you can use `dictionary.columns` and a macro to generate code that will rename everything at the end of your data step. In your case, there are two scenarios:

1. The word 'at' is in the string and there is a date
2. The word 'at' is not in the string and there is a date

Extract the relevant words from the string using these scenarios:

1. Find where 'at' begins and grab all letters in the column name up to that point
2. Find where any digit begins and grab all letters in the column name up to that point

Save the variable names and column names into pipe-delimited macro variable lists. These are useful because you can loop through these lists and easily grab each word individually. They act like an array in a very loose sense.

```
proc sql noprint;
    select name
         , CASE
              when(findw(name, 'at')) then substr(name, 1, findw(name, 'at')-1)
              else substr(name, 1, anydigit(name)-1)
           END
           as new_name
    into :names separated by '|'
       , :new_names separated by '|'
    from dictionary.columns
    where     libname = 'WORK'
          AND memname = 'HAVE'
          AND name NE calculated new_name
    ;
quit;

/* Generate code to rename the variables */
%macro rename;
    %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&names, |));
        %let name     = %scan(&names, &i, |);
        %let new_name = %scan(&new_names, &i, |);

        rename "&name"n = "&new_name"n;
    %end;
%mend;

data want;
    set have;

    %rename;
run;
```

If your data is large, you can save time by using `proc datasets` and rename in-place rather than create a new dataset to rename the variables.

```
proc datasets nolist;
    modify have;
    %rename;
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but the timestamp and the conversations I have to do are really dishomogeneous. I'd rather make each correction by hand in the code (with an appropriate "case when") and then rename all the variables' name massively with the correct name.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Stu Sztukowski I've a solution with the following code:

```
data base;
infile cards missover;
input 
NAME $ 'Quantity Value at 31/12/2019'n $ 'Value at 31/12/2019'n $ 'Yield Exp 31/12/2019'n $; datalines;
FIDO 12                          F                  1
ALFA 20                          2                  4
BETA 3                           5                  2
ETA  2                           B65                0
THETA 14                         A40                10
run;

proc sql ;
    create table BASE_COLUMN as
    select name 
    from sashelp.vcolumn
    where memname = "BASE"
  ;
quit ;

proc sql;
    update BASE_COLUMN
        set name = 
            case
                when name like "Quantity Value%" then "Quantity Value"
                when name like "Value at%" then "Value"
                when name like "Yield Exp%" then "Yield Exp"
            else name
end;
quit;


proc sql noprint;
    select name
         , CASE
              when name like "Quantity Value%" then "Quantity Value"
              when name like "Value at%" then "Value"
              when name like "Yield Exp%" then "Yield Exp"
              else name
           END
           as new_name
    into :names separated by '|'
       , :new_names separated by '|'
    from dictionary.columns
    where     libname = 'WORK'
          AND memname = 'BASE'
          AND name NE calculated new_name
    ;
quit;

%macro rename;
    %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&names, |));
        %let name     = %scan(&names, &i, |);
        %let new_name = %scan(&new_names, &i, |);

        rename "&name"n = "&new_name"n;
    %end;
%mend;

data BASE_CORRECT;
    set BASE;

    %rename;
run;
```

Thanks Again!

Comment: Much easier to just generate the old=new pairs directly into a single macro variable. `... catx('=',nliteral(names),nliteral(new_names)) into :renames separated by ' '...` then there is no need for macro, just use the list in the RENAME statement `rename &renames;`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than have the mapping data in a series of case when clauses, long term, your governance and coding practices might recommend using **control data** that drives the renaming process.  The control data can be in a permanent library and modified only as needed.  The examples here use the `WORK` library for convenience and demonstration.

Some examples of renaming control data

**Example 1**

Dataset: `Like_name_map`

```
LIKE               NEW_NAME
---------------------------------
Quantity Value%    Quantity Value
Value at%          Value
Yield Exp%         Yield Exp
```

**Example 2**
Dataset: `Regex_name_map`

```
PATTERN                                NEW_NAME
-----------------------------------------------
^(.+)( at)? *\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$     $1
```

Rewriting an entire data set in order just rename columns can be resource intensive, especially if the table is large or has constraints.  `Proc DATASETS` can be used to perform renaming and only modifies the header portion of an existing data set.

**Example 1** - control data are maps of like patterns

```
data base1 base2;
infile cards missover;
input 
  NAME $ 
  'Quantity Value at 31/12/2019'n $ 
  'Value at 31/12/2019'n $ 
  'Yield Exp 31/12/2019'n $
  z
; datalines;
FIDO  12   F    1  3
ALFA  20   2    4  1
BETA   3   5    2  4
ETA    2  B65   0  1
THETA 14  A40  10  5
run;

data work.like_name_map; length like $32 new_name $32;input
LIKE&              NEW_NAME&; datalines;
Quantity Value%    Quantity Value
Value at%          Value
Yield Exp%         Yield Exp
;

%macro rename_by_like(data, control=work.like_name_map);
  %local lib mem index;

  %let syslast = &data;
  %let lib = %scan(&syslast,1);
  %let mem = %scan(&syslast,2);

  %if %sysfunc(exist(work.__contents)) %then %do;
    proc sql; drop table __contents;
  %end;

  proc contents noprint data=&data out=__contents(keep=name);

  /* utilize the control data for locating matches and applying naming map */
  proc sql;
    select quote(trim(__contents.name))||'n='||quote(trim(control.new_name))||'n' as rename
    into :__rename1-
    from __contents 
    join &control as control
    on upcase(__contents.name) like upcase(trim(control.like))
    ;
  quit;

  %if &sqlobs %then %do;
    proc datasets nolist lib=&lib;
      modify &mem;
      rename
      %do index = 1 %to &sqlobs;
        &&__rename&index
      %end;
      ;
    quit;
  %end;
%mend;

%rename_by_like(base1)
```

will log

```
NOTE: The execution of this query involves performing one or more Cartesian product joins that
      can not be optimized.
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


NOTE: Renaming variable 'Quantity Value at 31/12/2019'n to 'Quantity Value'n.
NOTE: Renaming variable 'Value at 31/12/2019'n to Value.
NOTE: Renaming variable 'Yield Exp 31/12/2019'n to 'Yield Exp'n.

NOTE: MODIFY was successful for WORK.BASE1.DATA.
NOTE: PROCEDURE DATASETS used (Total process time):
```

**Example 2** - control data are maps of Perl regular expression patterns

```
data work.regex_name_map; length pattern $100 new_name $32; input
pattern&                             new_name&; datalines;
^(.+?)( at)? *\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$  $1
;

%macro rename_by_regex(data, control=work.regex_name_map);
  %local lib mem index;

  %let syslast = &data;
  %let lib = %scan(&syslast,1);
  %let mem = %scan(&syslast,2);

  %if %sysfunc(exist(work.__contents)) %then %do;
    proc sql; drop table __contents;
  %end;

  proc contents noprint data=&data out=__contents(keep=name);
  proc sql;
    select
      quote(trim(__contents.name))||'n' ||
      '=' || 
      quote(prxchange('s/'||trim(control.pattern)||'/'||trim(control.new_name)||'/',
                      1,
                      trim(__contents.name)
      ))||'n'
    into :__rename1-
    from __contents 
    join &control as control
    on prxmatch('/'||trim(control.pattern)||'/i', trim(__contents.name));
  quit;

  %if &sqlobs %then %do;
    proc datasets nolist lib=&lib;
      modify &mem;
      rename
      %do index = 1 %to &sqlobs;
        &&__rename&index
      %end;
      ;
    quit;
  %end;
%mend;

%rename_by_regex(base2)
```